# component angular

Tags: angular-routes

Incluir um módulo `login-home`, no `app.html`, na minha máquina está rodando normalmente, mas no servidor de produção aparece esse erro:

ERRO em:

> Digite LoginComponentHome em C: /projects/Jenkins/store.telcabos/src/app/components/register/login-home/login-home.component.ts 
>   é parte das declarações de 2 módulos: AppModule em C: / projetos / Jenkins / store.telcabos / src / app / app.module.ts e LoginhomeModule em C: / projetos / Jen kins / store.telcabos / src / app / componentes / register / login-home / login-home.module. ts! Por favor, considere mover LoginComponentHome em C: / projetos / Jenki ns / store.telcabos / src / app / componentes / register / login-home / login-home.component.ts para um módulo superior que importa AppModule em C: / projects / Jenki ns / store.telcabos / src / app / app.module.ts e LoginhomeModule em C: /projects/Jenkins/store.telcabos/src/app/components/register/login-home/login-home.module.ts. Você também pode criar um novo NgModule que exporte e inclua LoginComponentHome em C: /projects/Jenkins/store.telcabos/src/app/c omponents / register / login-home / login-home.component.ts e, em seguida, importe esse NgModule no AppModule em C: / projects, enkinsistore e telcabosisrciaPP / aPP module.ts e LoginhomeModule em C: /projects/Jenkins/store.telcabos/src/app/components/register/login-home/login-home.module.ts

Alguém teria uma solução?

Comment: Esta com importações redundantes! Confira suas importações, não realize importações duplas, ou mova a importação para um modulo raiz

Comment: E o código dos módulos? Tente remover o `LoginComponentHome` do `imports` e `declarations` do `AppModule`

Comment: Na verdade dupliquei o modulo login, porque precisava de um módulo especifico para home, o módulo login atual, não permite usar a tag <login>, pelo menos quando tentei, apareceu uma página em branco. Na minha máquina roda normalmente.

Comment: no app.module
import { LoginComponentHome } from './components/register/login-home/login-home.component';

declarations: [
  AppComponent,
  CategoryComponent,
  GroupComponent,
  NewsLetterComponent,
  LoginComponentHome
    
 ],